# Код системы рейтинга и званий в телеграм боте | python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Скажите, пожалуйста, как создать систему рейтинга в телеграм боте?
То есть, ввести такую переменную, которую админ чата может изменять.
Команда для админа в ответ на сообщение пользователя- "+{колличество репутации}",
бот отвечает "{юзернейм админа} повысил репутацию {юзернейм пользователя} на {колличество репутации}. Твоя новая репутация - {новая репутация (старая+та, которую дал админ)}".
Репутацию может повышать только админ. Репутация каждого пользователя - индивидуальная и хранится в базе данных или таблице гугл ексел.
По команде !профиль пользователя в строчке "Репутация - " будет показываться актуальная репутация пользователя.
Ещё существует определённая система званий, то есть когда репутация определённого пользователя достигает, к примеру, 50, то у него звание "Горожанин" в профиле меняется на "Торговец". И опять же по команде !профиль чтобы в строке "Твое звание - " у пользователей показывалось их актуальное звание.
Также как создать топ пользователей по их репутации? То есть, чтобы по команде !топ показывалось топ 5 пользователей с наибольшей репутацией.
Заранее спасибо! Буду премного благодарен!!!

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы вам кто-то написал такого бота? тогда вам на фриланс биржу, тут заказы не выполняют. А вот если у вас есть какие то наработки, то выкладывайте, задавайте вопросы